# Excel IF() on imported value always returns false

Tags: excel, vba

We have a software package from which we can export data (numbers and text)
to MS Excel. When I try an run a simple IF() formula on the imported data,
the formula always returns false.
If I
manually re-type the information into the cell then it is picked up - and a
*true* result is returned!
I have tried using the TRIM() function on the imported value in the IF(), but that did not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to know what type of information you have/type.

Comment: It is a number I type when testing the formula. 45, 46 or 47.

Comment: What does `=TYPE(A1)` return for your data? If it is a number, it should return 1, for text it should return 2.

Comment: It returns an error: "Invalid name". Hmmm?

Comment: Oh - sorry! It is a bit different in Danish... ;) it returns 2, so it would seem the problem lies here. However I cannot use the VALUE-function in my formula, because I have a list in the field where the formula is. (I didn't make the sheet, so it is not my choice).

Comment: I tried adding "" to the compare values in my IF instead - figuring that would do pretty much the same, but perhaps I'm wrong? =IF(TRIM(D1)="47";"Text1";IF(TRIM(D1)="46";"Text2";IF(TRIM(D1)="45";"Text3";"Text1")))

Comment: I need only to press F2 and then enter to make the formula respond as I want it to. As if the formula just isn't active on the loading time?

Comment: is the cell formatted as Text? Try changing the format to General or Numberic

Comment: That is already tried - if only... But thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps if I could work out a macro that does the F2 - enter-job... Is that possible?

Comment: I have tried to change the field parameter to a string, and importing that in stead, but the imported value is simply not registered by the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are comparing a text to a number. TRIM does not convert a text to a number, it only deletes the spaces.
Try this:

```
=IF(VALUE(TRIM(A1)))
```

Comment: A very relevant comment, but alas - it didn't fix the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

Following this link, that discusses a similar problem: http://www.appnitro.com/forums/topic/excel-does-not-identify-field-in-correct-date-format-after-import.

Thanks to all who tried to help me with this.